Struts2 (2.5.30): Poblem with directly adressing method in Action class via "!" Maybe DMI?
I had to upgrade an old project from struts 2.1.6 to 2.5.30. In the JSPs there are a lot of URLs referencing methods in actions with a !. I've never seen that before, but according to https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration this seems to be a valid way and everything worked fine before.
Example from one JSP:
<s:url  value="partPrices!listPurchasePrices.action?salesPartMasterPrice.headerId=%{salesPartMaster.id}"  var="listPurchasePrices" includeParams="get" />

struts.xml
<action name="partPrices" method="execute" class="com.abosco.scu.ais.action.SalesPartPrice">
  <result>/pages/prices.jsp</result>
  <result name="input">/pages/error.jsp</result>  
</action>

After upgrading i get the following error when clicking on the example link:
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [partPrices!listPurchasePrices] associated with context path [/sauterais].
Stacktraces
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [partPrices!listPurchasePrices] associated with context path [/sauterais]. - [unknown location]

com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:195)
org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:57)
org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:32)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:60)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:79)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsExecuteFilter.java:86)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:65)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

The action class, just in case. The methods are there.
package com.abosco.scu.ais.action;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Preparable;

import com.abosco.scu.ais.dao.SalesPartMasterDAO;
import com.abosco.scu.ais.dao.SalesPartMasterPriceDAO;
import com.abosco.scu.ais.model.SalesPartMaster;
import com.abosco.scu.ais.model.SalesPartMasterPrice;
import com.abosco.scu.ais.model.SalesPartMasterPriceExample;

public class SalesPartPrice extends UserAware implements Preparable
{
    /**
     * generated id
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2747412237989015409L;

    private static final BigDecimal ONE = new BigDecimal("1");
    private static final BigDecimal HUNDRET = new BigDecimal("100");

    private SalesPartMasterPriceDAO mSalesPartMasterPriceDAO;

    private SalesPartMasterDAO mSalesPartMasterDAO;

    private List<SalesPartMasterPrice> mSalesPartPrices;

    private SalesPartMaster mSalesPartMaster = new SalesPartMaster();

    private SalesPartMasterPrice mSalesPartMasterPrice = new SalesPartMasterPrice();

    public final static int SALES_PRICE = 1;

    public final static int PURCHASE_PRICE = 0;

    private int mPriceMode = PURCHASE_PRICE;

    /** Logging */
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(SalesPart.class);

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.opensymphony.xwork2.Preparable#prepare()
     */
    public void prepare() throws Exception
    {
        if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getId()!=null)
        {
            mSalesPartMasterPrice = mSalesPartMasterPriceDAO.selectByPrimaryKey(mSalesPartMasterPrice.getId());
            mPriceMode = StringUtils.equals(mSalesPartMasterPrice.getPriceType(), "V") ? SALES_PRICE : PURCHASE_PRICE;
        }
        if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getHeaderId()!=null)
        {
            mSalesPartMaster = mSalesPartMasterDAO.selectByPrimaryKey(mSalesPartMasterPrice.getHeaderId());
        }
        initEmptyValues(mSalesPartMasterPrice);
    }
    /**
     * for prevent null with i18n format
     */
    private void initEmptyValues(SalesPartMasterPrice price)
    {
        if (price!=null)
        {
            Double zeroDouble = new Double(0.0);
            if (price.getDiscount1()==null)
            {
                price.setDiscount1(zeroDouble);
            }
            if (price.getDiscount2()==null)
            {
                price.setDiscount2(zeroDouble);
            }
            if (price.getDiscount3()==null)
            {
                price.setDiscount3(zeroDouble);
            }
            if (price.getGrossPrice()==null)
            {
                price.setGrossPrice(zeroDouble);
            }
            if (price.getNetPrice()==null)
            {
                price.setNetPrice(zeroDouble);
            }
            if (price.getMaxDiscount()==null)
            {
                price.setMaxDiscount(zeroDouble);
            }
            if (price.getDiscountable()==null)
            {
                if (price.getPriceType()!= null && price.getPriceType().equals(SalesPartMasterPrice.PURCHASE_PRICE))
                {
                    price.setDiscountable("B");
                }
                else
                {
                    price.setDiscountable("");
                }
            }
            if (price.getAdditionalChargeFactor()==null)
            {
                price.setAdditionalChargeFactor(zeroDouble);
            }
            if (price.getConstruction()==null)
            {
                price.setConstruction(zeroDouble);
            }
            if (price.getConnectionCosts()==null)
            {
                price.setConnectionCosts(zeroDouble);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the salesPartMasterDAO
     *
     * @param salesPartMasterDAO The salesPartMasterDAO to set.
     */
    public void setSalesPartMasterPriceDAO(SalesPartMasterPriceDAO salesPartMasterPriceDAO)
    {
        mSalesPartMasterPriceDAO = salesPartMasterPriceDAO;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getId()==null)
        {
            return INPUT;
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String create() throws Exception {
        try
        {
            if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getHeaderId()==null)
            {
                return INPUT;
            }
            else
            {
                mSalesPartMaster = mSalesPartMasterDAO.selectByPrimaryKey(mSalesPartMasterPrice.getHeaderId());

                mSalesPartMasterPrice.setPriceType(SALES_PRICE == getPriceMode() ? SalesPartMasterPrice.SALES_PRICE : SalesPartMasterPrice.PURCHASE_PRICE);
                initEmptyValues(mSalesPartMasterPrice);
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

                boolean firstPrice = false;

                // check if the new price will be the first one
                if (SALES_PRICE == getPriceMode())
                {
                    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(getPricesList(mSalesPartMasterPrice.getHeaderId(), SalesPartMasterPrice.SALES_PRICE)))
                    {
                        firstPrice = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(getPricesList(mSalesPartMasterPrice.getHeaderId(), SalesPartMasterPrice.PURCHASE_PRICE)))
                    {
                        firstPrice = true;
                    }
                }

                if (firstPrice)
                {
                    //set default valid dates to jan an dec this year
                    mSalesPartMasterPrice.setValidFrom(new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR),Calendar.JANUARY,1).getTime());
                    mSalesPartMasterPrice.setValidTo(new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR),Calendar.DECEMBER,31).getTime());
                }
                else
                {
                    //set default valid dates to jan an dec nex year
                    mSalesPartMasterPrice.setValidFrom(new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR)+1,Calendar.JANUARY,1).getTime());
                    mSalesPartMasterPrice.setValidTo(new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR)+1,Calendar.DECEMBER,31).getTime());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            logger.error("Error during Price create",x);
            addActionError("Fehler bei der Preisanlage");
            addActionError(x.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String save() throws Exception {
        boolean newPrice = false;
        mPriceMode = StringUtils.equals(mSalesPartMasterPrice.getPriceType(), SalesPartMasterPrice.SALES_PRICE) ? SALES_PRICE : PURCHASE_PRICE;

        try
        {
            if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getId()==null)
            {
                newPrice = true;
                if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getDiscount1()==null)
                {
                    mSalesPartMasterPrice.setDiscount1(new Double(0.0));
                }
                if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getDiscount2()==null)
                {
                    mSalesPartMasterPrice.setDiscount2(new Double(0.0));
                }
                if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getDiscount3()==null)
                {
                    mSalesPartMasterPrice.setDiscount3(new Double(0.0));
                }
                if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getAdditionalChargeFactor()==null)
                {
                    mSalesPartMasterPrice.setAdditionalChargeFactor(new Double(0.0));
                }
                if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getConstruction()==null)
                {
                    mSalesPartMasterPrice.setConstruction(new Double(0.0));
                }
                if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getConnectionCosts()==null)
                {
                    mSalesPartMasterPrice.setConnectionCosts(new Double(0.0));
                }
                mSalesPartMasterPrice.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
                mSalesPartMasterPrice.setCreatedUser(getUser().getLoginName());
                mSalesPartMasterPrice.setCreatedDate(new Date());
                mSalesPartMasterPrice.setChangedUser(getUser().getLoginName());
                mSalesPartMasterPrice.setChangedDate(new Date());
                //check for valid range
                //Select * from VTEIPO where VPVEID='1bbfc3ea-67c3-4262-ac69-d24f1b90b8a5' AND VPPRTP='B' and VPBIDA>20090201 and 20090301>VPVODA
                if (mSalesPartMasterPriceDAO.checkDateRange(mSalesPartMasterPrice))
                {
                    mSalesPartMasterPriceDAO.insert(mSalesPartMasterPrice);
                    addActionMessage(getText("message.insert",new String[] {getText("message.priceinformation")}));
                }
                else
                {
                    addActionError(getText("message.priceerror"));
                    mSalesPartMasterPrice.setId(null);
                    return INPUT;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mSalesPartMasterPrice.setChangedUser(getUser().getLoginName());
                mSalesPartMasterPrice.setChangedDate(new Date());
                //check for valid range
                if (mSalesPartMasterPriceDAO.checkDateRange(mSalesPartMasterPrice))
                {
                    mSalesPartMasterPriceDAO.updateByPrimaryKey(mSalesPartMasterPrice);
                    addActionMessage(getText("message.update",new String[] {getText("message.priceinformation")}));
                }
                else
                {
                    addActionError(getText("message.priceerror"));
                    return INPUT;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            if (newPrice)
            {
                mSalesPartMasterPrice.setId(null);
            }
            logger.error("Error during Price save",x);
            addActionError("Fehler bei der Preisspeicherung");
            addActionError(x.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        initEmptyValues(mSalesPartMasterPrice);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport#validate()
     */
    public void validateSave()
    {
        mPriceMode = StringUtils.equals(mSalesPartMasterPrice.getPriceType(), SalesPartMasterPrice.SALES_PRICE) ? SALES_PRICE : PURCHASE_PRICE;
        //        <field name="salesPartMaster.status">
        //        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        //        <message>Bitte den Status auswählen</message>
        //        </field-validator>
        //        </field>
        //        <field name="salesPartMaster.partId">
        //            <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        //            <message>Bitte eine Teilenummer angeben</message>
        //            </field-validator>
        //        </field>
        if (mPriceMode == PURCHASE_PRICE)
        {
            if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getGrossPrice()==null)
            {
                addFieldError("salesPartMasterPrice.grossPrice", "Bitte den Bruttopreis angeben");
            }
        }
        if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getValidFrom() == null)
        {
            addFieldError("salesPartMasterPrice.validFrom", "Bitte das Gültigkeitsdatum angeben");
            return;
        }
        if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getValidTo() == null)
        {
            addFieldError("salesPartMasterPrice.validTo", "Bitte das Gültigkeitsdatum angeben");
            return;
        }
        if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getValidTo().before(mSalesPartMasterPrice.getValidFrom()))
        {
            addFieldError("salesPartMasterPrice.validTo", "BIS Datum kleiner als VON Datum");
        }
    }

    public String listPurchasePrices() throws Exception {
        if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getHeaderId()==null)
        {
            return INPUT;
        }
        else
        {
            mSalesPartPrices = getPricesList(mSalesPartMasterPrice.getHeaderId(), SalesPartMasterPrice.PURCHASE_PRICE);

            calculatePriceChange();
            Collections.reverse(mSalesPartPrices);
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    private List<SalesPartMasterPrice> getPricesList(UUID headerId, String priceType)
    {
        SalesPartMasterPriceExample search = new SalesPartMasterPriceExample();
        search.setOrderByClause("VPVODA, VPBIDA");
        search.createCriteria().andHeaderIdEqualTo(headerId)
                               .andPriceTypeEqualTo(priceType);

        return mSalesPartMasterPriceDAO.selectByExample(search);
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private void calculatePriceChange()
    {
        boolean firstElement = true;
        double oldNetPrice = 0.0;
        double oldGrossPrice = 0.0;

        for (SalesPartMasterPrice price : mSalesPartPrices)
        {
            double netPrice = price.getNetPrice() != null ? price.getNetPrice().doubleValue() : 0.0;
            double grossPrice = price.getGrossPrice() != null ? price.getGrossPrice().doubleValue() : 0.0;
            if (firstElement)
            {
                oldNetPrice = netPrice;
                oldGrossPrice = grossPrice;
                firstElement = false;
            }
            price.setGrossPriceChange(new Double(grossPrice-oldGrossPrice));
            price.setNetPriceChange(new Double(netPrice-oldNetPrice));
            price.setGrossPriceChangePercent(oldGrossPrice!=0.0 ? new Double(((grossPrice-oldGrossPrice)/oldGrossPrice)*100): new Double(0.0));
            price.setNetPriceChangePercent(oldNetPrice!=0.0 ? new Double(((netPrice-oldNetPrice)/oldNetPrice)*100): new Double(0.0));
            //store old prices
            oldNetPrice = netPrice;
            oldGrossPrice = grossPrice;
        }
    }

    public String listSalesPrices() throws Exception {
        if (mSalesPartMasterPrice.getHeaderId()==null)
        {
            return INPUT;
        }
        else
        {
            mSalesPartPrices = getPricesList(mSalesPartMasterPrice.getHeaderId(), SalesPartMasterPrice.SALES_PRICE);

            calculatePriceChange();
            Collections.reverse(mSalesPartPrices);
        }
        mPriceMode=SALES_PRICE;
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String recalculateNetPrices() throws Exception {

        SalesPartMasterPriceExample search = new SalesPartMasterPriceExample();
        search.createCriteria().andPriceTypeEqualTo(SalesPartMasterPrice.PURCHASE_PRICE);
        mSalesPartPrices = mSalesPartMasterPriceDAO.selectByExample(search);
        for (SalesPartMasterPrice price : mSalesPartPrices)
        {
            calculateNetPriceChange(price);
        }
        mSalesPartMasterPriceDAO.batchUpdate(mSalesPartPrices);

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String recalculateNetPricesTest() throws Exception {
        //prepare test table
        int rows = mSalesPartMasterPriceDAO.insertInTestTable();

        logger.info("Test Tabelle VTEIP2 gefüllt mit "+rows+ "Preissätzen");
        addActionMessage("Test Tabelle VTEIP2 gefüllt mit "+rows+ "Preissätzen");

        SalesPartMasterPriceExample search = new SalesPartMasterPriceExample();
        search.createCriteria().andPriceTypeEqualTo(SalesPartMasterPrice.PURCHASE_PRICE);
        mSalesPartPrices = mSalesPartMasterPriceDAO.selectPriceTestByExample(search);
        for (SalesPartMasterPrice price : mSalesPartPrices)
        {
            calculateNetPriceChange(price);
        }
        mSalesPartMasterPriceDAO.batchUpdate(mSalesPartPrices);
        addActionMessage("Nettopreisberechung in VTEIP2 durchgeführt.");

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    /**
     * @param price
     */
    private void calculateNetPriceChange(SalesPartMasterPrice price)
    {

//        double netPrice = (price.getGrossPrice().doubleValue() * (1.0-(price.getDiscount1().doubleValue()/100.0)) * (1.0-(price.getDiscount2().doubleValue()/100.0)) * (1.0-(price.getDiscount3().doubleValue()/100.0)));
//
//        BigDecimal net = new BigDecimal(new Double(netPrice).toString());
//        net = net.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
//        price.setNetPrice(new Double(net.doubleValue()));

        BigDecimal discountMultiplicator1 = ONE.subtract(new BigDecimal(price.getDiscount1().toString()).divide(HUNDRET));
        BigDecimal discountMultiplicator2 = ONE.subtract(new BigDecimal(price.getDiscount2().toString()).divide(HUNDRET));
        BigDecimal discountMultiplicator3 = ONE.subtract(new BigDecimal(price.getDiscount3().toString()).divide(HUNDRET));

        BigDecimal net = new BigDecimal(price.getGrossPrice().toString()).multiply(discountMultiplicator1).multiply(discountMultiplicator2).multiply(discountMultiplicator3);
        net = net.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        price.setNetPrice(new Double(net.doubleValue()));
    }
    /**
     * Return the salesPartMasterPrice.
     *
     * @return the salesPartMasterPrice.
     */
    public SalesPartMasterPrice getSalesPartMasterPrice()
    {
        return mSalesPartMasterPrice;
    }

    /**
     * Return the salesPartPrices.
     *
     * @return the salesPartPrices.
     */
    public List<SalesPartMasterPrice> getSalesPartPrices()
    {
        return mSalesPartPrices;
    }

    /**
     * Return the priceMode.
     *
     * @return the priceMode.
     */
    public int getPriceMode()
    {
        return mPriceMode;
    }

    /**
     * Return the priceMode.
     *
     * @return the priceMode.
     */
    public boolean isPurchasePrice()
    {
        return mPriceMode == PURCHASE_PRICE;
    }



    /**
     * Set the priceMode
     *
     * @param priceMode The priceMode to set.
     */
    public void setPriceMode(int priceMode)
    {
        mPriceMode = priceMode;
    }

    /**
     * Set the salesPartMasterPrice
     *
     * @param salesPartMasterPrice The salesPartMasterPrice to set.
     */
    public void setSalesPartMasterPrice(SalesPartMasterPrice salesPartMasterPrice)
    {
        mSalesPartMasterPrice = salesPartMasterPrice;
    }

    /**
     * Set the salesPartMasterDAO
     *
     * @param salesPartMasterDAO The salesPartMasterDAO to set.
     */
    public void setSalesPartMasterDAO(SalesPartMasterDAO salesPartMasterDAO)
    {
        mSalesPartMasterDAO = salesPartMasterDAO;
    }

    /**
     * Return the salesPartMaster.
     *
     * @return the salesPartMaster.
     */
    public SalesPartMaster getSalesPartMaster()
    {
        return mSalesPartMaster;
    }
}


I've read up about DMI and SMI from above link and from my understanding i now have to disable SMI, which was the only change i made to the struts.xml.
<package name="item" namespace="/" extends="struts-default" strict-method-invocation="false" >

Still didn't help. What looks a bit suspect to me is the [unknown location] in the error message but otherwise i have no clue what to look for.

Why did you disable SMI? It is a good thing.

If i understood the explanation of the link in my post correctly. If enabled (which is default since 2.5) it requires to explicitly allow methods. This is not the case in the given project and i suspected it to be the reason for the error.

Do you want we discuss what did you suspect? Or do you want to find a solution to your problem?

@RomanC i'd like to understand why it doesn't work anymore and find a solution. Preferably while keeping the direct reference to the action class methods in the URL, since this is used a lot in the project. Defining distinct actions (which i already tried) works in terms of calling the action, but creates unrelated issues with how the JSPs are displayed. So i would like to avoid it if possible.

A lot of things happened since the version releases from 2.1 till 2.5. This is obvious why your actions didn't map. You can find the answer in the abovelinked duplicate.
